# Paramiko file copying extremely slow

Tags: python-2.7, paramiko

Im trying to copy large files (~1.5G ) from a CentOS6.6 to another Centos6.6

(python 2.7.8 , paramiko 1.11.0)

when using simple scp , files are copied at around 40MB/s and when using paramiko , it goes down to 2MB/s

here is the code that preforms the copying:

```
 def create_paramiko_sftp(self, ip, port, username, password):
        transport = paramiko.Transport((ip, port))
        transport.connect(username=username, password=password)
        sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
    return sftp

def read_in_chunks(self, file_object, chunk_size=(4 << 20)):
    # generator that yields the data in chunks
    while True:
        data = file_object.read(chunk_size)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data

def copy_file2(self, ip, src, dest):
    sftp = self.create_paramiko_sftp(ip, 22, <usrname>, <psswd>)
    i = 0
    start_time = time.time()
    f = open(src, 'rb')
    op = sftp.open(dest, mode='w+')
    for piece in self.read_in_chunks(f):
        i += 1
        # print '\r{0}'.format(i),
        op.write(piece)
    op.close()
    f.close()
    sftp.close()
    self.Log("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time), INFO)
```

as can be seen , im copying the file in chunks. Is it possible i need to configure one of the system port differently in order to achieve the same speed?

i looked around and didn't find any answer that addressed the issue

Comment: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/60

Comment: Same here. 1.1 MByte/s via loopback. This issue with paramiko still seems to be unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue downloading similarly large amounts of data. I was never able to speed it up but found the `subprocess` module to offer a better solution for me. It allows the execution of shell commands. Here's an example:

```python
import subprocess

command = 'ssh user@host "tar -cf - ~/foo" > foo.tar'

p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

# Print command line output
for line in p.stdout:
    print(line.decode("utf-8").rstrip())

# Wait for command line process to finish before proceeding
p.communicate()
```

You can change the command to any command you would use in the command line. I even had success running this on Windows 10 using [cmder](http://cmder.net/). You could replace the tar command with scp, rsync, etc.

#### Authentication using an SSH key

I was unable to get this working using a username and password, so I generated an SSH key. For those who don't know what that is (I didn't), here's a summary.

Using the command line tool `ssh-keygen`, you can create a public and a private key that allow you to authenticate with remote computers without having to provide a password. An example commmand is `ssh-keygen -t rsa`. [This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2) tutorial has more information.

After generating the keys locally, copy the public key to the remote computer. This can be done through a shell command (`ssh-copy-id user@host`), or by pasting the public key found on the local computer (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote computer. If that directory and file do not exist, follow these commands:

```bash
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 0700 ~/.ssh
touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 0644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
nano ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Once the `authorized_keys` file is open, paste the public key into it and then save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) and exit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>) the file. The next time you use SSH with that computer, you won't have to use a password.